# null pointer exception on ConnectivityManager

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, connectivity

My aplication class is activity to get aplication context and use it else where.isOnline is called from some class JSONParser, which is not an activity. isOnline is called by getJSONFromUrl(). Test is method of B class.test() is called by  activity LoginActivity. However i am getting nullpoint and dont understand why. 
is it because i am gtting context in wrong way or i pass context to  ConnectivityManager incorecly or something else?
method isOnline

```
private static Boolean isOnline(){

        context = MyApplication.getAppContext();
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
               for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                     return true;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         return false;
    }
```

myaplication class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

error

```
06-05 09:29:22.104: D/dalvikvm(526): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1033 objects / 82800 bytes in 52ms
06-05 09:29:52.734: D/frakc@mail.ru(526): emails
06-05 09:29:56.414: D/f(526): onItemSelected

06-05 09:30:00.446: W/KeyCharacterMap(526): No keyboard for id 0
06-05 09:30:00.446: W/KeyCharacterMap(526): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-05 09:30:01.814: D/parsing data to login(526): true
06-05 09:30:01.824: W/dalvikvm(526): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.JSONParser.isOnline(JSONParser.java:87)
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:114)
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:51)
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.LoginActivity$1$1.run(LoginActivity.java:144)
06-05 09:30:01.824: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole logcat?

Comment: class B in description is JSONParser and activity A is LoginActivity

Comment: Ok can you tell me to which line corresponds LoginActivity.java:144 ? Is it where you instantiate the ConnectivityManager?

Do you have the right permissions in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

Comment: Conectivity manager is initialised only in isOnline which is inside JSONParser.  LoginActivity.java:144  send parameters to UserFunctions, where they are procesed and send to JSONParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your context is coming null. pass the application context in your method and then use that context for the refere.. it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
```

to

```
MyApplication.context = this;
```

Comment: i thought MyApplication.getAppContext(); will give me proper context, is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things if you haven't done yet :

**1.** Add you application class in your Manifest in your applications name like this

```
 <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyApplication"
```

**2.** Add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```